# How to specify slope by several fixed effects to a random effect in mixed effects regression in R's lme4?

Tags: multiple-regression, mixed-model, lme4-nlme

In the past I have seen regression models with random effect slopes by one fixed effect, for example:

```
mod = lmer(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + (x1|rand1) + (x1|rand2), data = dat, REML=FALSE)
```

Is it possible to add a slope by several fixed effects (e.g. x1, x2, and x3) to a random effect in mixed effects regression in R's lme4? If, so how? What would the syntax look like?

**EDIT**

To make the question more specific, let me include a specific example from a data set I am using. Doing some exploratory plotting and analysis, I plotted the Kendall correlations between the three fixed variables.

[image]

As you can see in the plots, the correlations are very high, which would seem to justify including interactions between then in my mixed effects model. Specifically, there is a linear relationship between x1 and x3, and a quadratic relationship between x1 and x2, and x2 and x3. The correlations seem to suggest that I should acknowledge the dependence of the variables when I specify the slope for the two random effects. What is the most appropriate way to specify this in lme4?

Comment: Are you asking about `(x1|rand1)+(x2|rand1)`? Yes, this is possible.

Comment: Sure, but are the variables dependent or independent in this syntax? Why not (1 + x1| rand1) or (x1 - 1|rand1)? There are different theoretical motivations for these choices, but I just don't know what they mean and I'd was hoping someone would address that in their answer.